# Join two tables and assign values from second table to each date of the first table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=edc2641a0e33f3075d64c584982b5b65)**

```
/* Table Costs */
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date DATE,
    costs_per_day DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO costs
(date, costs_per_day)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', '400'),
('2020-01-02', '400'),
('2020-01-03', '400'),
('2020-01-04', '400'),
('2020-01-05', '400'),
('2020-01-06', '400'),
('2020-01-07', '400'),
('2020-01-08', '400');


/* Table Sales */
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    country VARCHAR,
    sales_share DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, country, sales_share)
VALUES 
('2020-01-03', 'DE', '0.45'),
('2020-01-03', 'NL', '0.10'),
('2020-01-03', 'FR', '0.35'),
('2020-01-06', 'DE', '0.20'),
('2020-01-06', 'FR', '0.70'),
('2020-01-06', 'NL', '0.10');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
date_list     |  event_date    |    country    |    sales_share     | costs_per_day_per_country|
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
2020-01-01    |  NULL          |      DE       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-01    |  NULL          |      FR       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-01    |  NULL          |      NL       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
2020-01-02    |  NULL          |      DE       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-02    |  NULL          |      FR       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-02    |  NULL          |      NL       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------| 
2020-01-03    |  2020-01-03    |      DE       |       0.45         |         180.00           |
2020-01-03    |  2020-01-03    |      FR       |       0.35         |         140.00           |
2020-01-03    |  2020-01-03    |      NL       |       0.10         |          40.00           |
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
2020-01-04    |  NULL          |      DE       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-04    |  NULL          |      FR       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-04    |  NULL          |      NL       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
2020-01-05    |  NULL          |      DE       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-05    |  NULL          |      NL       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-05    |  NULL          |      FR       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
2020-01-06    |  2020-01-06    |      DE       |       0.20         |          80.00           |
2020-01-06    |  2020-01-06    |      NL       |       0.70         |         280.00           |
2020-01-06    |  2020-01-06    |      FR       |       0.10         |          40.00           |
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
2020-01-07    |  NULL          |      DE       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-07    |  NULL          |      NL       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-07    |  NULL          |      FR       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
--------------|----------------|---------------|--------------------|--------------------------|
2020-01-08    |  NULL          |      DE       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
2020-01-08    |  NULL          |      NL       |       0.33         |         133.33           | 
2020-01-08    |  NULL          |      FR       |       0.33         |         133.33           |
```

---

I want to merge the tables `costs` and `sales` with with the follwing conditions:

1. All dates from table `costs` are listed.
2. Each date from table `costs` gets assigned all available countries from table `sales`.
3. The `sales_share` from table `sales` is assigned if the `dates` from both tables are matching.
4. If they are not matching the `sales_share` is divided equally to the number of countries.
5. `costs_per_day` are multiplied with the `sales_share` to get `costs_per_day_per_country`.

---

So far I was able to develop this query:

```
SELECT 
c.date AS date_list,
t1.event_date,
t1.country,
t1.sales_share,
c.costs_per_day * t1.sales_share AS costs_per_day_per_country
FROM costs c
LEFT JOIN

  (SELECT
  DISTINCT s.event_date,
  s.sales_share,
  s.country
  FROM sales s
  ORDER BY 1,2) t1 ON t1.event_date = c.date

ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

With this query I am already able to do bullet point `1)`, `3)` and some part of `5)` from the conditions. 
I think my biggest issue is to put the countries to each date of the list as described in `2)`.

How do I have to modify the query to get the entire expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CROSS JOIN with distinct countries to assign each date all available countries, then join with sales by date and country. Calculate costs_per_day_per_country depending on is t1 joined or not. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
c.date AS date_list,
t1.event_date,
co.country,
coalesce(t1.sales_share,
         (1-sum(COALESCE(t1.sales_share,0)) over (partition by c.date))/ --share to divide 
          count(case when t1.sales_share is null then 1 end) over(partition by c.date) --number of countries not joined
        ) as  sales_share,         
case when t1.sales_share is NULL --Not joined
     then c.costs_per_day * 
         (1-sum(COALESCE(t1.sales_share,0)) over (partition by c.date))/ --share to divide 
          count(case when t1.sales_share is null then 1 end) over(partition by c.date) --number of countries not joined
     else c.costs_per_day * t1.sales_share 
end AS costs_per_day_per_country
          
FROM costs c 
   CROSS JOIN (select distinct s.country from sales s) co
   LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
  DISTINCT s.event_date,
           s.sales_share,
           s.country
      FROM sales s) t1 ON t1.event_date = c.date AND t1.country = co.country

ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7a729fcbe68f0efb6f276517db43d2bf)